# EF change detection does not seem to recognize my updates on an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create an `AddOrUpdate` method. Unfortunately, it seems that the change detection is not kicking in. I just don't see what I am doing wrong here.

Consider the following model:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public OrderDetails OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetails 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

This entities should have a one-to-one relationship to each other. An order can't exist without OrderDetails and the other way round.

So this is what my EntityTypeConfigurations looks like:

```
public class OrderEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        this.HasRequired(e => e.OrderDetails)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(e => e.Order);

        this.ToTable("Orders");
    }
}

public class OrderDetailEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderDetails>
{
    public OrderDetailEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        this.ToTable("OrderDetails");
    }
}
```

Now I've got a repository called `OrderRepository`, with a method called `AddOrUpdate()`.

```
public class OrderRepository 
{
    public OrderRepository(OrderDbContext context)
    { 
        // ... 
    }

    public bool Contains(Order order)
    {
        var result = this.context.OrderSet.SingleOrDefault(e => e.OrderId == order.OrderId);

        return result != null;
    }

    public Order GetOrderByOrderId(string orderId)
    {
        return this.context.OrderSet
            .Include(e => e.OrderDetails)
            .SingleOrDefault(e => e.OrderId == orderId);
    }

    public void AddOrUpdate(Order order)
    {
        if (this.Contains(order))
        {
            var result = this.GetOrderByOrderId(order.OrderId);
            result = order;
        }
        else
        {
            this.context.OrderSet.Add(order);
        }

        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

However in the case where `this.Contains(order)` evaluates to true the assignment from `order` to `result` does not get detected from the ChangeDetection mechanism. The call to `SaveChanges()` returns 0. Why is that?

---

The following approach seems to work, but *feels* kind of hacky.

```
public void AddOrUpdate(Order order)
{
    if (this.Contains(order))
    {
        var result = this.GetOrderByOrderId(order.OrderId);

        order.Id = result.Id;
        order.OrderDetails.Id = result.OrderDetails.Id;

        this.context.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(order);
        this.context.Entry(result.OrderDetails).CurrentValues.SetValues(order.OrderDetails);
    }
    else
    {
        this.context.OrderSet.Add(order);
    }

    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What's wrong by using the `Update` method from the `DbContext`?

Comment: Sorry, but what `Update` method are you referring to? Maybe this method is only available to EF-Core?

Comment: How are you getting order instance that u pass to addorupdate function?

Answer (score 1):

Simple assignment `result = order` will not work, cause EF is tracking(if chage tracking is enabled) object fetched via `this.GetOrderByOrderId(order.OrderId)` call and stored in `result` variable and not the `order` one. So you will need either copy needed fields from `order` to `result` somehow or play with `Attach`(usually would not recommend though).

Comment: Thx for replying. I have updated my question. I am not sure if this is the right way to go...

Comment: TBH looks fine to me. Depends on what you actually want.